# Несколько скриптов с асинхронными операциями на странице, как выполняются?

Tags: javascript, api, typescript, promise, модули

Допустим у меня есть три скрипта:

```html
<script src="script1.js" type="module">
<script src="script2.js" type="module">
<script src="script3.js" type="module">
```

В первом скрипте я пишу две синхронных операции, одна из которых генерирует асинхронное выполнение:

```js
console.log("First module");
new Promise((res) => res()).then(() =>console.log("First module's promise"))
```

Во втором:

```js
console.log("Second module");
setTimeout(() => console.log("Second module setTimeout"), 0);
```

А в третьем:

```js
console.log("Third module");
```

Вывод в консоль будет таким:

```html
First module's promise
Second module
Third module
Second module setTimeout
```

В связи с чем у меня три вопроса:

1. Почему промис первого модуля выполнился раньше синхронной операции
   второго
2. Почему setTimeout второго модуля выполнился выполнился позже,
   синхронной операции третьего модуля
3. В какой момент Event Loop разрешает выполнятся асинхронным операциям
   в модулях(я знаю, что в момент освобождения стека, но когда стек
   можно считать освобожденным, когда закончено выполнение одного
   модуля или всех)

Нуу как то так, буду рад если ответ будет как можно более развернут.

P.S. На данный момент мне непонятен принцип выполнения асинхронных операций в модулях

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Почему промис первого модуля выполнился раньше синхронной операции второго

Не могу сказать точно, но похоже что, на импорт модуля идёт больше времени чем на окончание `Promise`-а, который сразу выполняется.

> 2. Почему setTimeout второго модуля выполнился выполнился позже, синхронной операции третьего модуля

Если мы посмотрим на реальную скорость завершения таймера, то тогда мы можем увидеть, что `setTimeout` завершается примерно через 5-15 миллисекунд:

```js
const now = performance.now()

setTimeout(() => console.log(performance.now() - now), 0)
```

То-есть, на импорт и исполнение второго модуля, нужно меньше времени чем на завершение `setTimeout`. Соответственно поэтому, мы можем увидеть сначала логи третьего модуля, а позже один лог второго

> 3. В какой момент Event Loop разрешает выполнятся асинхронным операциям в модулях(я знаю, что в момент освобождения стека, но когда стек можно считать освобожденным, когда закончено выполнение одного модуля или всех)

Стек вызовов можно считать пустым (освобождённым), когда все модули были выполнены.

Comment: в первом пункте просто повторен несколько раз сам вопрос: почему выполнился раньше, без какого либо ответа, во втором - просто какой-то поток сознания. Что показывают два примера - непонятно.

Comment: @Grundy, как у вас много свободного времени...

Comment: первый пункт - неверный. второй - тоже

Comment: @Grundy хорошо, тогда расскажите как будет правильно.